# AWS Sam build provided.al2 with Go workspaces

Tags: go, lambda, makefile, aws-sam

I have a project set up with several lambdas written in go managed by a go.work workspace.  Going by Aws documentation I have a Makefile in my lambda function directory to build the function:

```
build-UserPutFunction:
    set GOOS=linux
    set GOARCH=amd64
    go build -o bootstrap
    cp ./bootstrap $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)\
```

template.yaml:

```
UserPutFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambda/user/user_put
      Handler: bootstrap
      Runtime: provided.al2
```

This works fine when I run make build-UserPutFunction from the function directory itself.  When I try to build using sam build, however, I get error "package user is not in std."  My workspace makes use of a user module with user struct outside of lambda function.  How does one get sam to build when using go workspaces?

edit:
I got the build to work by making sure the go.work, template.yaml, and Makefile are at the root of project directory.  Then moving each build command to this root Makefile.  Now how to copy files to build directory?